# Intrinsics equivalent to the CUDA Type Casting Intrinsics __double2loint, __double2hiint and __hiloint2double

Tags: c, cuda, sse, intrinsics, avx

I am trying to figure out, what are the CPU equivalents to the CUDA Type Casting intrinsics [__double2loint](http://datamining.xmu.edu.cn/documentation/cuda4.1/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__CAST_g8f685cb937cc96c273d197da7b1633f1.html), [__double2hiint](http://datamining.xmu.edu.cn/documentation/cuda4.1/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__CAST_ge8bbbe2efda5aa6f087c94e1e56463e8.html) and [__hiloint2double](http://datamining.xmu.edu.cn/documentation/cuda4.1/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__CAST_g5853355db4780e81fb09ac911a8f2def.html).

I guess that _mm_cvttsd_si32 may be equivalent to __double2loint (is it correct?), but I didn't find equivalents for __double2hiint and __hiloint2double. Is possible to implement fast versions of such functions in C?

Comment: You can easily write these functions in standard C using a `union`.

Comment: `_mm_cvttsd_si32` is not a reinterpretation, it's a conversion. You could reinterpret with `_mm_castsi128_ps` etc but as mentioned you can do it in C itself.

Comment: How to get started in order to implement any of the CUDA type casting intrinsics above?

Comment: Is faster the code in standard C than a code using intrinsics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express these operations via a union. This will not create extra overhead with modern compilers as long as optimization is on (`nvcc -O3 ...`).

```
double hiloint2double(int hi, int lo)
{
    union {
        double val;
        struct {
            int lo;
            int hi;
        };
    } u;
    u.hi = hi;
    u.lo = lo;
    return u.val;
}

int double2hiint(double val)
{
    union {
        double val;
        struct {
            int lo;
            int hi;
        };
    } u;
    u.val = val;
    return u.hi;
}

int double2loint(double val)
{
    union {
        double val;
        struct {
            int lo;
            int hi;
        };
    } u;
    u.val = val;
    return u.lo;
}
```